# Secrets in Docker without Swarm

Tags: docker, secret-management

I am using Docker, but not Swarm (or any other orchestration) for a project.

Is there a way to leverage Docker Secrets without Swarm?

Answer (score 3):

You can use docker secrets a bit differently using `docker-compose` without having to use swarm. [See this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#secrets) for the official documentation.

## Example:

1. Create a simple compose file like so,

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5.2
    env_file:
      - ./db.env
    secrets:
      - rootpass
      - dbpass
      - mysqldb
      - mysqluser
    restart: always
```

2. Now add the following in the end

```
secrets:
  rootpass:
    file: /tmp/root_pass
  dbpass:
    file: /tmp/db_pass
  mysqldb:
    file: /tmp/mysql_db
  mysqluser:
    file: /tmp/mysql_user
```

3. Inside those files, keep your password, username, database name etc. in plain text. Then simply deploy the containers `docker-compose up -d`.

It's similar to how you define volumes and networks in a compose file.

Keep in mind that this isn't true secret implementation. Here's [the github PR](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/4368) that added this feature, along with the [main file](https://www.github.com/dnephin/compose/tree/8c4fc4bc2ed82648f7a6ab7e14a492368f997415/compose%2Fconfig%2Fconfig.py) if you're interested.

Comment: The first link is now dead.

Comment: So, the file is the source on the host? If so, where do you find it in the container?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the documentation in https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb?tab=description, your solution can be this:

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.7
    secrets:
      - rootpass
      - dbpass
      - mysqldb
      - mysqluser
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/rootpass
      MARIADB_DATABASE_FILE: /run/secrets/mysqldb
      MARIADB_USER_FILE: /run/secrets/mysqluser
      MARIADB_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/dbpass
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

secrets:
  rootpass:
    file: ./cf/root_pass
  dbpass:
    file: ./cf/db_pass
  mysqldb:
    file: ./cf/mysql_db
  mysqluser:
    file: ./cf/mysql_user
```

Comment: In your solution, the secrets are in some files beside the `docker-compose.yaml` file, which are plain text. So, who to use that plain text as encrypted in `docker-compose` without `swarm`?